# protractor expect callback and display on html report success/fail

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

`expect("yes").toEqual("yes");` In html report it will show passed with correct sign.

`expect("yes").toEqual("no");`
It will throw the error.

How to make expect call function based on response success/fail, and how to write custom message in HTML report for **success and fails**, instead of showing **passed**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. Thats limitation of your HTML reporter how it is recognizes test failure/pass. Usually you don't need customize success outputs in tests , but you could provide custom error message, to be more informative than - 'Expect true to be false'. Check this:

```
expect("yes").toEqual("no", "Here is your custom error message");
expect("yes").toEqual("yes", "expecting yes to be yes");
```

Almost all jasmine matchers support this.